# What is good practice for generating verbose output?

Tags: c++, verbosity

what is good practice for generating verbose output? currently, i have a function

```
bool verbose;
int setVerbose(bool v)
{
    errormsg = "";
    verbose = v;
    if (verbose == v)
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

and whenever i want to generate output, i do something like

```
if (debug)
     std::cout << "deleting interp" << std::endl;
```

however, i don't think that's very elegant. so i wonder what would be a good way to implement this verbosity switch?

Comment: Dosen't your `setVerbose` always return 0?

Comment: yes, unless something extremely esoteric happens. it's just that i have a bunch of setSomething() functions which all return 0 if the operation was successful and -1 if not. so it's just a question of having a consistent interface ...

Comment: I don't understand this code. Is this a case of editing gone awry?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simplest way is to create small class as follows(here is Unicode version, but you can easily change it to single-byte version):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum log_level_t {
    LOG_NOTHING,
    LOG_CRITICAL,
    LOG_ERROR,
    LOG_WARNING,
    LOG_INFO,
    LOG_DEBUG
};

namespace log_impl {
class formatted_log_t {
public:
    formatted_log_t( log_level_t level, const wchar_t* msg ) : fmt(msg), level(level) {}
    ~formatted_log_t() {
        // GLOBAL_LEVEL is a global variable and could be changed at runtime
        // Any customization could be here
        if ( level <= GLOBAL_LEVEL ) wcout << level << L" " << fmt << endl;
    }        
    template <typename T> 
    formatted_log_t& operator %(T value) {
        fmt % value;
        return *this;
    }    
protected:
    log_level_t     level;
    boost::wformat      fmt;
};
}//namespace log_impl
// Helper function. Class formatted_log_t will not be used directly.
template <log_level_t level>
log_impl::formatted_log_t log(const wchar_t* msg) {
    return log_impl::formatted_log_t( level, msg );
}
```

Helper function `log` was made template to get nice call syntax. Then it could be used in the following way:

```
int main ()
{
    // Log level is clearly separated from the log message
    log<LOG_DEBUG>(L"TEST %3% %2% %1%") % 5 % 10 % L"privet";
    return 0;
}
```

You could change verbosity level at runtime by changing global `GLOBAL_LEVEL` variable.

Comment: i like this answer. i really only need this very simple stdout logging, no file/network stuff ever needed (i hope). so i will try to keep the number of external dependencies low and go for my own implementation.

Comment: I find this solution clever and very helpful, I wish I can give it 10 upvotes! :-)

Comment: I believe the GLOBAL_LEVEL variable will be problematic across translation units, am I right? How would you implement this variable?

Comment: just put it in a `namespace` @quimnuss

Answer (score 9):

```
int threshold = 3;
class mystreambuf: public std::streambuf
{
};
mystreambuf nostreambuf;
std::ostream nocout(&nostreambuf);
#define log(x) ((x >= threshold)? std::cout : nocout)

int main()
{
    log(1) << "No hello?" << std::endl;     // Not printed on console, too low log level.
    log(5) << "Hello world!" << std::endl;  // Will print.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: would there be a possibility to 'include' the std::endl into the log() definition?

Comment: Define `log(x)` can be easily replaced with inline function. Is there reason to use defines here?

Comment: Regarding std::endl: none that I know of. If you want less code, you could always use typedef, such as _e. Regardig #define/inline: no reason.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [log4cpp](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Does that have asynchronous logging capabilities?

Comment: I don't know if it does or not. sorry.

Comment: I agree that using a proper logging library is the answer rather than hand-coding something, although Log4cpp appears to be moribund. http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/index.html on the other hand is alive and kicking. According to the web site it does have support for asynchronous logging, though i don't think that's relevant to this question.

Comment: A more modern alternative: https://github.com/gabime/spdlog
Very fast, quite intuitive to use, and well maintained.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your functionality in a class that supports the << operator which allows you to do something like

```
class Trace {
   public:
      enum { Enable, Disable } state;
   // ...
   operator<<(...)
};
```

Then you can do something like

```
trace << Trace::Enable;
trace << "deleting interp"
```

Comment: I like the idea of wrapping an error-logging system in a class. You can store things like location of output file and whatnot in the class, too.

Comment: just so i understand you correctly: i would create an instance of Trace class called trace before? and then another question: why is Trace::Enable enough to set the state to Enable? i'm still fairly new to c++, and am a bit confused. perhaps some three lines more in your idea would help me understand better what's going on. but i definitely like your idea!

Comment: Yes, you would need to create an instance of teh Trace class; this could be statically or locally to each component that wished to use it. 

The Trace::Enable would toggle an internal flag within the Trace class (an instance of the state enum). This would act very much like std::hex allows std::cout to output in hex format instead of decimal. 

Since you will be writing operator<< you can support Trace::Enable (or any other state specifiers such as verbosity and such)

Comment: Andreash, `Trace::Enable` would be enough to set the state to `Enable` because you're going to write code for the `<<` operator that makes your class know how to handle that flag. There's no magic here. Personally, I'd just make an ordinary member function and say `trace.enable()`.

Answer (score 3):

**1.** If you are using g++ you could use the -D flag, this allows the compilator to define a macro of your choice.

Defining the

For instance :

```
#ifdef DEBUG_FLAG
 printf("My error message");
#endif
```

**2.** I agree this isn't elegant either, so to make it a bit nicer :

```
void verbose(const char * fmt, ... )
{
va_list args;  /* Used as a pointer to the next variable argument. */
va_start( args, fmt );  /* Initialize the pointer to arguments. */

#ifdef DEBUG_FLAG
printf(fmt, &args);  
#endif
/*This isn't tested, the point is to be able to pass args to 
printf*/
}
```

That you could use like printf :

```
verbose("Error number %d\n",errorno);
```

**3.** A third solution easier, and more C++ and Unix like is to pass an argument to your program that is going to be used  - as the macro earlier - to initialize a particular variable (that could be a global const).

Example :
$ ./myprogram -v

```
if(optarg('v')) static const verbose = 1;
```